# parsing tool (batch) that reads out specific lines and gives me the average, lowest and highest time the path took

Tags: parsing, batch-file

So I have a .log and I need to read out those lines for example:

"

2012-06-22 03:06:25  INFO  Mohd Tahar, Azrul Haza ExecuteSingleContext duration: 251.9628 - Page_Load\RefreshGridAction\GetOrderObjectByOrderID

2012-06-22 03:06:25  INFO  Mohd Tahar, Azrul Haza ExecuteSingleContext duration: 195.32 - Page_Load\RefreshGridAction\GetOrderListByOrderID

"

and puts them down into a seperated .txt file sorted by the instructions like "Page_Load..." but only those instruction with the highest, lowest and average time the instruction took. (the number such as 251.9628)
I'm a total newbie with this stuff and i'm also only in an apprenticeship but my boss wants me to do this...
I don't know how to code this and also i dont have any other experience.. :D
And i don't even have a clue what to do. 
An other problem is that there are many line i don't even need such as:

"

2012-06-22 03:06:23 ERROR System Account Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

or

TSystems.CE.Contes.Data.EntityService.Person.getPersonID(String samAccountName

or

2012-06-22 03:04:02     INFO      System Account GetWorkOrderListByOrderIdWoTypeIdPreCompiled - compilation needed: False : 2.9298

or

2012-06-22 03:04:02     INFO      System Account --Warmup finished--

"

can anyone help me?
Thanks Denis =)

Answer (score 0):

Read about these tools: grep, sed or GNU awk. One of them could be used to extract the data you need without a lot of work. There's a lot of tutorials on the net. Good luck :)

For your particular need (counting average, etc.) I would probably go for GNU awk.